# Joins vs Join like queries - Are they equivalent?

Tags: sql, performance, join

I expect this question has been asked multiple times, with different twists.. I want to try and get a generic and comprehensive understanding of this topic though. (does it belong in programming SO? ..)

Lets say I have a table for `sports` and a table for `matches`. `matches`, among other fields has a `sport_id` column, and this is a 1:many relationship.

Lets say I want to list out sports which have matches on day X. I could do this in 3 ways that I can think of..

Nested queries - easy to reason?

```
SELECT * 
FROM sports 
WHERE id IN (SELECT sport_id FROM matches WHERE <DATE CHECK>)
```

From/where - easy to write?

```
SELECT sports.* 
FROM sports, matches 
WHERE sports.id = matches.sport_id 
  AND <DATE CHECK>
```

Joins - I am not too familiar, so forgive any mistakes

```
SELECT * 
FROM sports 
JOIN matches ON sports.id = matches.sport_id 
WHERE <DATE CHECK>
```

There might be other methods based on variations of Join which might be better suited here, inner join perhaps..

What I want to know is how I can compare these 3 on the basis of

1. Equivalent response (same rows returned?)
2. Performance on DB
3. Are all of them 1 query/network call or ?
4. Are any of these answers db engine dependent?
5. How might I choose among these?
6. Is #2 syntactic sugar for #3? is #1? Or are they optimized to #3 on some/all cases?

Comment: The second and third are both joins -- the second is an implicit join, the third is an explicit join. They're completely equivalent.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second and third forms are completely equivalent (except you have an extra comma in the third version). `FROM sports, matches` is an *implicit* join, `FROM sports JOIN matches` is an *explicit* join. Implicit joins are the earlier form, explicit joins are more modern and generally preferred by database experts.

The version with `WHERE IN` is almost the same, but there are some differences. First, `SELECT *` will return columns from both tables in the join, but will only return columns from `sports` in the `WHERE IN` query. Second, if a row in `sports` matches multiple rows in `matches`, the joins will return a row for each pair of matches (it performs a cross product),  while `WHERE IN` will just return the row from `sports` once regardless of how many matches there are.

Performance differences are implementation dependent. There shouldn't be any difference between the explicit and implicit joins, they're just syntactic sugar. However, databases don't always optimize the `WHERE IN` queries the same. For instance, when I've used `EXPLAIN` with MySQL, `WHERE IN` queries often perform a full scan over the outer table, matching the column against the index of the table in the subquery, even though the subquery might only return a small number of rows. I think some people have told me that recent MySQL versions are better at this.

They will all be just 1 network call. All queries are just a single call to the database server.

BTW, there's another form that you didn't list, using `WHERE EXISTS` with a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT *
FROM sports s
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM matches m 
              WHERE s.id = m.sport_id AND <DATE CHECK>)
```

Performance differences between this and `JOIN` will again be implementation-dependent.

Comment: Hey, thanks, still digesting.. the `,` was unintentional, removed

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I think about your questions

**1.Equivalent response (same rows returned?)**

- for first QUERY where you usered   `IN` Oprator my answer is NO (you get same number of rows but only columns from table `sports` ) 
  and second and third is almost same

**2.Performance on DB**

First  In oprator is Slower then join beacause
The IN is evaluated (and the select from b re-run) for each row in a, whereas the JOIN is optimized to use indices and other neat paging tricks...

ANSI JOIN Syntax

```
SELECT fname, lname, department 
FROM names INNER JOIN departments ON names.employeeid = departments.employeeid
```

Former Microsoft JOIN Syntax

```
SELECT fname, lname, department 
FROM names, departments 
WHERE names.employeeid = departments.employeeid
```

If written correctly, either format will produce identical results. But that is a big if. The older Microsoft join syntax lends itself to mistakes because the syntax is a little less obvious. On the other hand, the ANSI syntax is very explicit and there is little chance you can make a mistake.

**3.Are all of them 1 query/network call or ?**

-Trial 1 result for `IN`

-Trial 2 result for `Microsoft JOIN`,

-Trial 3  result for `ANSI JOIN`
[image]
**4.Are any of these answers db engine dependant?**

(Sorry I didt got ans for this question)

**5.How might I choose among these?**

I sugges you shuold use `ANSI JOIN`

**6.Is #2 syntactic sugar for #3? is #1? Or are they optimized to #3 on some/all cases?**

-I think NO as I mentioned above #3 syntex is more batter 
  as per my past experience
 I ran across a slow-performing query from an ERP program. After reviewing the code, which used the Microsoft JOIN syntax, I noticed that instead of creating a LEFT JOIN, the developer had accidentally created a CROSS JOIN instead. In this particular example, less than 10,000 rows should have resulted from the LEFT JOIN, but because a CROSS JOIN was used, over 11 million rows were returned instead. Then the developer used a SELECT DISTINCT to get rid of all the unnecessary rows created by the CROSS JOIN. As you can guess, this made for a very lengthy query. I notified the vendor’s support department about it, and they fixed their code.

The moral of this story is that you probably should be using the ANSI syntax, not the old Microsoft syntax. Besides reducing the odds of making silly mistakes, this code is more portable between database, and eventually, I imagine Microsoft will eventually stop supporting the old format, making the ANSI syntax the only option

Comment: Hi, thanks, still digesting, but your "columns" issue is why I specifically put `sports.*` in the 2nd one.. I assumed Join will only select `*` from the `FROM` tables.. is this not the case?

Comment: The third (join) query also returns only colums from sports. Could you explain why in your image the microsoft syntax says 70 returned but join only returns 42?