# How to go from a relation to a relation of associated model in Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have often had this sort of situation

```
class Post
   has_many :comments

end
```

Now if I have a relation of posts, how would I get the relation of all comments on that posts.

What I am looking for is

```
Post.where(user: user).comments
```

But this wont work. Am I missing something obvious here? This seems like a common use case.

Basically when you do `Post.where(user: user).includes(:comments)` we are preloading all the requisite comments already, what I want is to access them directly, without `Post.where(user: user).includes(:comments).map{|p| p.comments}.flatten.uniq` or something like that..

Comment: I can't test this right now but how about Post.where(user: user).map(&:comments)

Comment: @Nimir that is basically what i am doing with some syntactic sugar

Comment: Its looking like what I am looking for doesnt exist.. which is odd to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd define a scope

`scope :comments_in_user_posts, -> (user) { where(user: user).includes(:comments).map{|p| p.comments}.flatten }`

Then use it like `Post.comments_in_user_posts(user)`.

**EDIT:**

Another option is to use `Comment.where(post: Post.where(user: user))`

Comment: This is not really adding anything extra.. Just abt code org.. Is there no fix?

Comment: Maybe something like `Comment.where(post: Post.where(user: user))`?  I don't think there is a way of doing exactly what you want without going way too deep into ActiveRecord.

Comment: Hmm.. your second option might be the best option... let me wait a while to see if any come along. Can you add that to your answer?

Comment: That is breaking the chainability. Now you can't write something like `Post.comments_in_user_posts(user).recent` unless you write the `comments_in_user_posts(user)` at the very end... but if you define another method like that, then you could never use both together.

Comment: Accepting for the edit, since I believe this was the first to come up with that.

Answer (score 1):

you can also create in `Post` model static method:

```
def self.user_comments(user)
    Comment.where(post: Post.where(user: user))
end
```

and then call:

```
Post.user_comments(user)
```

Comment: This method seems the simplest, but is not what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get `comment` objects, then implement the logic in your `Comment` class.

You can define the scope like:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post

  scope :from_user, ->(user_id) { joins(post: :user).where(users: {id: user_id} }
end
```

So that you can call

```
Comment.from_user(current_user.id)
```

Comment: very interesting syntax, but is similar to the other solutions

Comment: well, this only hits the database once, not like `Comment.where(post: Post.where(user: user))` that  makes 2 queries... but in terms of getting the results, yes, both are the same.

Comment: Are you sure it makes 2 queries? It may look like that but I believe it does 1 over all, which contains an implicit join ( select where in)

Comment: Take a look to your log to be sure. Anyway, implicit joins are deprecated in rails 4.1, so you should not use them

Comment: I verified with a slightly different relation of Leagues which `has_many` matches.`Match.where(league: League.all)` gave `SELECT `matches`.* FROM `matches`  WHERE `matches`.`league_id` IN (SELECT `leagues`.`id` FROM `leagues`)` on 4.1.5

Comment: Wow, I have to admit that it is a very interesting query (though I think that is not an implicit join). Now the question is: are subqueries more efficient than joins?

Comment: I think that is a different SO question of mine :P http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463848/joins-vs-join-like-queries-are-they-equivalent Yeah.. not implicit join. Subqueries should be faster than 2 individual queries atleast though, to answer your orig comment

Answer (score -1):

you need to mention in comment model, belongs_to :post.

```
    class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :post  
    end
```

Now when you are saving any comment related to post. Make sure the @post object is present.

```
            @post.comments.create(name: "New comment")
```

You can try and check there things in rails console. Now when you see the comment object. It should have the post_id present.
So now

> post_obj.comments

give the array of comments and `comment.post` will give the related post.

Comment: I am not operating on one post object, but an arbitrary relation which might evaluate to any number of post objects.